# how to pass variables to .prn file to print on thermal printer in java

Tags: java, barcode

My requirement

I wanted to print bar code labels along with some patients' details for lab management system. For that I created a .prn file to print using ZEBRA TLP 2844 printer.
As per image [BARCODE CODE LABEL DESIGN PRINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDaHx.jpg) label design PATNAME,AGESEX,WARD are dynamic values
How to get those details from database and print them using prn file in java ?

Comment: What did you try so far? How do you create the .prn file and what's the problem setting the values there?

Comment: i created .prn file using ZebraDesigner 2 and i don't know how to set the dynamic values from database .how can i set values dynamically on a single button click i wanted to generate print.

Comment: Well, that depends on what you actually do and what your problems are. Don't you know how to read data from the database? Don't you know how to read and edit the .prn file? Did you look for tutorials on the database issue? Did you look for either libraries that can write .prn files or have a look at the format specification? If it's a simple text file you could try to do a simple search and replace with the data read from the db.

Comment: My code :public static void main(String args[]){
         
         PrintService printer = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
         System.out.println(printer.getName()); 
         try {
          /*   String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", "C:\\Users\\Santosh\\Desktop\\san.bat"};
             Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
             */
             Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start /B C:\\Users\\Santosh\\Desktop\\san.bat");
         } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

Comment: You may have noted that posting code in a comment is a little awkward. Please [edit] your question and add your well-formatted code there. Btw, just skimming over it it seems like you just call some batch file. We'd either have to know that that one does or why you aren't using the `PrintService` you seem to aquire (and also what library that is if it isn't in the JDK).

Answer (score 0):

We simply create the PRN files and add "variables" enclosed in curly braces: {myCode}.

When printing, we load the file, do a simple regex match and with that we can find all variables and later fill in the data, before we send it via network to the printer, e.g.:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(template);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    while(m.find()) {
        String key = template.substring(m.start() + 1, m.end() - 1);
        String replacement = lookupVariable(key);           
        m.appendReplacement(result, Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement));
    }
    m.appendTail(result);
```

Where 'template' is your PRN file read into a string, containing variables in curly braces.
The function `lookupVariable(String)` is something you implement to lookup the actual value for a given variable (look it up in a Map, in the database, wherever). In the end, you can use a ByteArrayOutputStream and OutputStreamWriter to convert everything to bytes with the right encoding to send it to the printer.

You could also use a templating engine like Velocity Templates.

Comment: how to find variables and fill data in .prn file using java. How can i achieve it?

Comment: That's literally what I wrote in my answer. I'm not going to write that for you though, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: can u please share me any example regarding how to find variables and fill data in prn file...actually i am searching but i didn't  get any source for that.

Comment: THIS IS MY .PRN File 
I8,A,001


Q203,024
q831
rN
S4
D7
ZT
JF
OD
R212,0
f100
N
A112,96,2,1,1,2,N,"<TIME>"
A272,96,2,1,1,2,N,"<DATE>"
A378,95,2,1,1,2,N,"Date     :"
A270,124,2,1,1,2,N,"<WARD>"
A377,123,2,1,1,2,N,"Bill No  :"
A281,155,2,1,1,2,N,"<AGESEX>"
A378,156,2,1,1,2,N,"Age/Sex :"
A308,187,2,1,1,2,N,"<PATNAME>"
A377,186,2,1,1,2,N,"Name :"
B356,66,2,1,2,6,34,B,"<PATTYPE><BILLNO>"
P1

Comment: there you go. I added some code. Like I said, it's just a simple text search and replace operation using regular expressions.

Comment: ok thanq. i know how to do replace operation using regular expressions but how to do in .prn file i am not having any idea.can u please help me on it ...